# how to solve this error: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

i used List to store the value, its working correctly if the data is limited, if the data is exceed more 15o in counts, then i am getting the following error
Index was outside the bounds of the array...Plz suggest an idea to overcome this problem.

```
List<string> code = new List<string>();
private void btn_browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult fileopen = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;           
    txt_filename.Text = filename;
    try
    {
        StreamReader readtxtfile = new StreamReader(filename);
        String line = null;

        string str = null;
        char[] separate = { ',' };
        string[] words;
        while ((str = readtxtfile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            words = str.Split(separate);                        
            code.Add(Convert.ToString(words[0]) + '-' + Convert.ToString(words[2]).Trim());  
        }                    
    }
```

Comment: ...make a bigger array? dynamically expand it? can't help if you don't want to provide more details.

Comment: can you paste some code?

Comment: Can you show us some code where you're accessing the data?

Comment: We'd need more information and some sample code on this one. It looks like you're trying to iterate through more items than actually exist in the List

Comment: paste the code ...and also how much do you think the size should be? If you can't fix the size you need a different data structure..

Comment: hi i have edited the questions, and how to set the size...

Comment: where is the error message coming from separate or words ? can you please paste the exception trace ?

Comment: hi ashutosh raina, it reads all the data and finally it showing error in catch part as Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: words = str.Split(separate);  this returns less than 3 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not because of your list but it came from your array "words". First check length of array like this

```
 words = str.Split(separate);  
 if(words.Length>2) 
 {                     
   code.Add(Convert.ToString(words[0]) + '-' + Convert.ToString(words[2]).Trim());  
 }
```

Make sure that whenever length of array is less then 2 it will not add in your list.

Hope this helps...